# MySql crashes in VPS

Tags: mysql

I have a VPS in GoDaddy, which is crashing MySql service at frequent times.

Here is the log file that may help to help me.

```
160425 09:24:53 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/mysql/s166-62-85-17.secureserver.net.pid ended
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x593491]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x59c2bd]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x6ea5d1]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x972d7d]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0xa2ad41]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0xaad67a]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0xaaba64]
160425 09:24:52 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
160425 09:24:47 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/mysql/s166-62-85-17.secureserver.net.pid ended
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x593491]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x59c2bd]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x6ea5d1]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x972d7d]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0xa2ad41]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0xaad67a]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0xaaba64]
160425 09:24:46 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
160425 09:24:41 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/mysql/s166-62-85-17.secureserver.net.pid ended
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x593491]

mysql has failed. Contact your system administrator if the service does not automagically recover.
```

Please help me to recover it!
Thanks.

Comment: Is that `mysqld.err`?

Answer (score 0):

Did you make any changes in my.cnf file recently? Most of the time MySQL fails to start due to any incorrect changes made in its conf file.

Next option is to check the ownership and permission of /var/lib/mysql. It should be owned by MySQL user and not the root user.